# How to sort two columns at once using sorted()

Tags: python, sorting, csv, python-3.x

I have a .csv file which holds two columns which I want to sort.
I want to sort the first column alphabetically and the second one by highest number to lowest.

I used `sortedColumn = sorted(csv_opener,key=operator.itemgetter(0))` to sort the first column alphabetically but I also want to do the same thing for the second column. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You mean you want a *subsort*? Sort the second column when the first column is equal?

Comment: When I use sortedColumn = sorted(csv_opener,key=operator.itemgetter(0)) it sorts the first column, but if I change it to sortedColumn = sorted(csv_opener,key=operator.itemgetter(1)) it will sort the second column but the first one will still remain unsorted

Comment: Right, which sort is the *main* sort order? Alphabetically on column 0, then *or equal values in column 0*, sort by column 1 in descending order? It never hurts to add examples to your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can sort by two aspects by having the `key` callable return a tuple.

I'm assuming that the second column is a string convertable to an integer:

```
sortedColumn = sorted(csv_opener, key=lambda row: (row[0], -int(row[1])))
```

By returning *negative* values from `row[1]` you can sort from highest-to-lowest, while the main sort is done or `row[0]` in alphabetical order.

So for the sample rows:

```
Alpha, 10
Beta, 30
Alpha, 42
Gamma, 81
Beta, 10
```

the sorted output gives you:

```
Alpha, 42
Alpha, 10
Beta, 30
Beta, 10
Gamma, 81
```

sorting first alphabetically on the first column, and then *for equal values in the first column*, the rows are sorted in descending order on the second column.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Martijn Pieters already provided a perfect answer, but I think it is worth checking out [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) DataFrame for dealing with CSV data in case you have not considered it.

You can use [pandas.read_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) to read the CSV input as a DataFrame and then use [DataFrame.sort_values()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to sort it any way you want.

To add an example, let's first generate some random sample data

```py
from faker import Factory
from random import randint, choice
import pandas

fake = Factory.create()
names = [fake.name() for i in range(5)]
nums = [randint(1, 50) for i in range(5)]
data = []
for i in range(10):
    data.append((choice(names), choice(nums)))

df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=("Names", "Nums"))
```

Resulting in, for example

```
    Names                   Nums
0   Jeffry Wintheiser       25
1   Dr. Corine Sporer PhD   25
2   Jeffry Wintheiser       17
3   Emmett Reilly           17
4   Jeffry Wintheiser       17
5   Emmett Reilly           33
6   Jeffry Wintheiser       33
7   Lilah Purdy             17
8   Emmett Reilly           22
9   Miss Julie Wisoky       25
```

Then you can use the sort_values as follows

```py
df.sort_values(["Names", "Nums"], ascending=[True, False])
```

Resulting in

```
    Names                   Nums
1   Dr. Corine Sporer PhD   25
5   Emmett Reilly           33
8   Emmett Reilly           22
3   Emmett Reilly           17
6   Jeffry Wintheiser       33
0   Jeffry Wintheiser       25
2   Jeffry Wintheiser       17
4   Jeffry Wintheiser       17
7   Lilah Purdy             17
9   Miss Julie Wisoky       25
```